# Renaming files with incremented number in the middle of the name using powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

I've searched long and hard for this, but cannot seem to locate a means of completing the renaming of files within multiple directories.  The issue is that I need to insert a unique number sequence in the middle of a file name.  Here are the examples of my file names:

```
8675309_FileName1_ExtraSuff1_Extrastuff2 and some more stuff_012345.html
2020202_FileName2_ExtraSuff1_Extrastuff2 and some more stuff_012345.html
... etc.
```

Renamed to insert a copy of the 1st 7 fields, a numeric sequencing and a date as in the following:

```
8675309_8675309_00001_2022_FileName1_ExtraSuff1_Extrastuff2 and some more stuff_012345.html
2020202_2020202_00002_2022_FileName2_ExtraSuff1_Extrastuff2 and some more stuff_012345.html
... etc.
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

$i = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.html |
ForEach-Object{
Rename-Item -Path $*.FullName -NewName (($*.BaseName -split '*')[0] + '*' + ('{0:D5}' -f $i) + '*2022' + '*Performance_Eval*' + ($*.BaseName -split '*')[1] + ($*.BaseName -split '*')[2] + ($*.BaseName -split '*')[3] + '*' + ($*.BaseName -split '*')[4] + $_.Extension )
$i++
}

This gives me most of what I need, but not the additional first 7 characters:

8675309_00001_2022_FileName1_ExtraSuff1_Extrastuff2 and some more stuff_012345.html

Ho can I tweak this script to bring in the initial characters?

Answer (score 0):

Since your file names seem to have a structure or a unique character  you can split them on you could use something like this:

```
$i = 1 
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.html | 
ForEach-Object{
    $SplitName = $_.BaseName -split '_'
    $NewName = ((@($SplitName[0]) * 2) -join '_') + '_' + ('{0:D5}' -f $i) + '_2022' + ($SplitName[1..($SplitName.Length -1)] -join '_') + $_.Extension 
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName
    $i++
}
```

I'm curious: why do you need the same sequence of numbers twice?

Comment: It is getting closer.  I have multiple "_" in some of the files so this logic cuts out the remaining file name.  An actual file name in question would be like the following:

2020202_FileName2_ExtraSuff1_Extrastuff2 and some more stuff_012345.html

Comment: How should one recommend something meaningful when there aren't all necessary information? Please add **ALL NEEDED** information to your question.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't realize it would matter until I tried what you'd laid out.  I'll update the original with all the info as I found out about another change to the need, too.